# How do I identify and replace out of range data in my data frame with NA?

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I identify and replace out of range data in my data frame with NA?

I am currently using the following code to identify outliers using a box plot and then manually deciding which ones are out of range (for example the scale is 1-4 and the data point is negative) and removing them.

```
>boxplot(data$scale1, data = data)
>outliers <- boxplot(cw$N, plot=FALSE)$out
>outliers
>data$scale1[data$scale1==-7.58] <- NA
```

I'm manually doing this for each variable as they all have different cut off points for being out of range and I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does your data follow some trend? If the data points are following some specific trend, then you could fit the trend and consider data points which are too far from the trend to be outliers.

Comment: You could write your cutoffs to a dataframe and apply them for each variable. @Heikki: I don't see a scenario where this approach would be appropriate

Comment: thank you! @tobiasegli_te that sounds like what I'm after, I was just unsure on how to do it if each variable has a different cut off point, do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to follow the comments you could go the following way:

```
# Make up some data
data <- data.frame(scale1=(c(0,-1,2,4,3,2,1,1,8,5)))

# Define scale min and max
scale1.min <- 0
scale1.max <- 4

# Set NAs for Outliers
data$scale1[data$scale1 < scale1.min | data$scale1 > scale1.max] <- NA
```

As Tobias already pointed out you can easily do this for multiple variables:

```
# Again make up some data
data <- data.frame(scale1=(c(0,-1,2,4,3,2,1,1,8,5)))
data["scale2"] <- data$scale1 - 1
data["scale3"] <- data$scale1 + 2
data["scale4"] <- data$scale1 + 5

# Define your cut off points
scale.min <- c(0,-1,2,3)
scale.max <- c(4,2,4,8)

for(i in 1:length(scale.min))
{
  data[,i][data[,i] < scale.min[i] | data[,i] > scale.max[i]] <- NA 
}
```

Hope that helps.